# XCUITest - How to access UI element on WebView screen from Google Mobile Ads SDK

Tags: webview, uiwebview, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

I am using XCUITest for UI test automation, most of the app is only native and I can access elements by `accessibilityIdentifiers` or simply by `label`. I have a problem when testing that ad opens because I cannot access the **close button**  on ad WebView screen. Web view is coming from Google Mobile Ads SDK for iOS.

I tried to access the element with `app..buttons["Close Advertisement"].tap()` but it did not work, it never taps the close button.

When I try it in debugger `po XCUIApplication().buttons["Close Advertisement"].tap()` returns me :

```
    t =    67.80s     Tap "Close Advertisement" Button
    t =    67.80s         Wait for ios.development to idle
    t =    67.82s         Find the "Close Advertisement" Button
    t =    67.86s         Check for interrupting elements affecting "Close Advertisement" Button
    t =    67.89s         Synthesize event
    t =    67.98s         Wait for ios.development to idle
0 elements
```

This is the full hierarchy of the screen when I execute `po XCUIApplication().debugDescription`

````
  Window (Main), 0x600003cd47e0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630778878896.4>
    Other, 0x600003cd4700, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630742447520.6>
      Other, 0x600003cd4620, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630742449600.8>
    Other, 0x600003cd4540, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630742912976.229>
      Other, 0x600003cd4460, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630739951984.230>
        Button, 0x600003cd4380, {{0.0, 0.0}, {42.0, 42.0}}, label: 'Close Advertisement', Disabled <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630739216816.231>
        Other, 0x600003cd42a0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630777385136.232>
          WebView, 0x600003cd40e0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630769439744.233>
            WebView, 0x600003cd4000, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630768846336.236>
              WebView, 0x600003cd4e00, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630769495040.237>
                Other, 0x600003cd4ee0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 5843420293174919168.9999>
                  Other, 0x600003cd4fc0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233423230208.3>
                    Other, 0x600003cd50a0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421369008.4>
                      Other, 0x600003cd5180, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421369040.5>
                        Other, 0x600003cd5260, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421402864.6>
                          Other, 0x600003cd5340, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421478464.7>
                            Other, 0x600003cd5420, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421481056.9>
                              Other, 0x600003cd5500, {{159.0, 303.0}, {57.0, 61.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421480800.10>
                              Other, 0x600003cd55e0, {{327.0, 0.0}, {48.0, 48.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421483680.11>
                                Other, 0x600003cd56c0, {{327.0, 0.0}, {48.0, 48.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421488304.19>
                                  Other, 0x600003cd57a0, {{339.0, 12.0}, {24.0, 24.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421489808.22>
                                  Other, 0x600003cd5880, {{339.0, 12.0}, {24.0, 24.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421486112.23>
                              Other, 0x600003cd5960, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 24.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421483712.12>
                              Other, 0x600003cd5a40, {{8.0, 635.0}, {24.0, 28.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421482512.13>
                              Other, 0x600003cd5b20, {{40.0, 627.0}, {8.0, 40.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421482544.14>
                                Other, 0x600003cd5c00, {{0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421492128.20>
                              Other, 0x600003cd5ce0, {{34.0, 662.0}, {6.0, 5.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421482608.15>
                              Other, 0x600003cd5dc0, {{0.0, 662.0}, {48.0, 5.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421484160.16>
                              Other, 0x600003cd5ea0, {{253.0, 624.0}, {111.0, 31.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421484192.17>
                                Other, 0x600003cd5f80, {{253.0, 624.0}, {111.0, 31.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421496224.21>
                                  StaticText, 0x600003cd6060, {{277.0, 632.0}, {62.0, 15.0}}, label: 'Learn More' <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421493056.24>
                              Other, 0x600003cd6140, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421484256.18>
                          Other, 0x600003cd6220, {{0.0, 0.0}, {25.0, 20.0}} <AX element pid: 67437, elementOrHash.elementID: 140233421478944.8>
              Other, 0x600003cc9180, {{342.0, 0.0}, {30.0, 667.0}}, label: 'Vertical scroll bar, 1 page', value: 0% <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630777539728.238>
              Other, 0x600003cc9260, {{0.0, 634.0}, {375.0, 30.0}}, label: 'Horizontal scroll bar, 1 page', value: 0% <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630777538944.239>
          Other, 0x600003ce32c0, {{0.0, 0.0}, {376.0, 668.0}} <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630826768976.234>
          StaticText, 0x600003ce31e0, {{160.0, 0.0}, {55.5, 22.0}}, label: 'Test Ad' <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630826625872.235>
  Window, 0x600003ce3100, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630783264592.5>
    Other, 0x600003cf4540, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630777978208.7>
      Other, 0x600003cd6300, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}} <AX element pid: 67431, elementOrHash.elementID: 140630742527888.9>```
````

Comment: the description clearly says this button is disabled. So maybe you should perform some actions before tapping on it?

Comment: @SmartMonkey I am not sure how can I make it available. My first thought was that it is disabled in the first 5 seconds of the ad, when you cannot close the ad, but it seems disabled even after that.

Comment: You should addd as many information as possible – Screenshots, URLs, code etc. It would help others to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there are couple of solutions.

1. do u want to test the ads? If not then what you can do is disable the ads using the launchArguments. This way you don’t have to worry about handling ads.
2. If u can not disable the ads then get the screen coordinates of the ad close button. This can be done via getting the web view container and relatively calculate the coordinates of the close button tap area. Then it will merely be a call of tap function on the screen.